# Codeigniter how to call a controller function via JQuery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have a list of products displayed in a table each of which has a checkbox to allow the user to select that product. I want to be able to perform other operations on the selected products once the user clicks on a button.

So far, I have JQuery code attached to the button which builds an array of the IDs of the selected products, but now I’m stuck. I’d like to be able to call a controller at this stage and pass the array to it; it could then perform operations on the selected items and display the results in another view for example.

My JQuery code is as follows: (it’s very verbose as it contains lots of debugging messages)

```
/*
Respond to the clicking of the 'With Selected->[Update Retail Outlets]' button
*/
$('#btn_uro').click(function() {
    alert('Update Retail Outlets');
    var w = 0;
    var str_status;
    var sel_array = [];
    $('.chk_sel_pdt').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
          str_status = "Checked";
          sel_array.push($this.val());
        } else {
          str_status = "Unchecked";
        }
        console.log (w + ": " + $(this).val() + " - " + str_status);
        w++;
    });
    console.log(sel_array);   

    // now try to send the array to a CI controller so that it can process the
    //   update request.
```

Can anyone tell me how I can call a controller function from here and pass sel_array[] to it.
I appreciate that this may be the wrong approach entirely so please feel free to suggest an alternative.

Thanks in advance. G.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting it in array you can just concatenate a string of ids like in your code

```
var selectedProducts = "";
$('.chk_sel_pdt').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
      str_status = "Checked";
      selectedProducts += $this.val()+","; 
    } else {
      str_status = "Unchecked";
    }
    console.log (w + ": " + $(this).val() + " - " + str_status);
    w++;
});
```

and send this data to an ajax call to controller function as a post attribute

```
$.ajax({
      url: "controller_name/action_name",
      data:{ selected_products: selectedProducts},

 });
```

in controller you can just use PHP [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to convert these ids in array and perform your business logic there.

In success of ajax you can do anything with your UI elements as per your response.

Happy Coding
Uzair

Comment: Thanks Uzair, that's a very elegant solution. However when I call the controller function it doesn't appear to run. That is, the controller function loads a View, but the view doesn't appear. If I inspect the GET structure using Firebug all of the View is right there in the HTML tab, but CI is not loading it into my browser. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Hi unplugngo, You need to return that html in a variable like  $html = $this->load->view($view_name,$data,true); it will store that view in a variable and return that variable (preferably in json) to ajax response and parse that json in your js success and show that html data where ever your want using jQuery $(element).html() method. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The logic which is given by Uzair is good. adding to that if in case you dont want to make AJAX call then the below code will be helpful

```
 $('#btn_uro').click(function() {
    alert('Update Retail Outlets');
    var w = 0;
    var str_status;
    var sel_str = "";
    $('.chk_sel_pdt').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
            str_status = "Checked";
            if(sel_str == "")
                sel_str = $this.val();
            else
                sel_str = sel_str + "," + $this.val();
        }
        console.log (w + ": " + $(this).val() + " - " + str_status);
        w++;
    });
    console.log(sel_str);
    $form = $('<form>');
    $form.attr('action',"ACTUAL URL").attr('method','POST');
    $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name','selectedproducts').attr('value',sel_str).appendTo($form);
    $form.appendTo('body'); 
    $form.submit();
})
```

You can get `selectedproducts` as a `post` variable in your controller.

Comment: Thank you - works very nicely. I'm not sure I understand it all just yet, but I'll drill down later on. Nice one :-)